# cannot import name 'Flask' from 'flask' while using Zappa and Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, aws-lambda, zappa

I'm getting this error while trying to deploy using Zappa from my Windows 10 machine.

```
[ERROR] ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from 'flask' (unknown location)
```

The output of `zappa deploy dev` is

```
    Uploading tm-ffsdfds-dev-1605479772.tar.gz (92.1MiB)..
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 96.6M/96.6M [00:41<00:00, 2.35MB/s]
Uploading handler_tm-ffsdfds-dev-1605480208.zip (12.9MiB)..
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 13.5M/13.5M [00:06<00:00, 2.19MB/s]
Scheduling..
Scheduled 309f8de5a71660e32f2033230157b644eba42-handler.keep_warm_callback with expression rate(4 minutes)!
Uploading tm-ffsdfd-dev-template-1605480327.json (1.6KiB)..
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1.67k/1.67k [00:00<00:00, 18.8kB/s]
Waiting for stack tm-ffsdfds-dev to create (this can take a bit)..
 75%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▎                    | 3/4 [00:09<00:03,  3.10s/res]
Deploying API Gateway..
Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 502 response code.
```

and this is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import logging
import json

from Common.logger import logging_setup
from Common.config import Config

logging_setup.setup_logging()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/extract', methods=['POST'])
def extract():  
    try:
        ...       
        return response_json
    except Exception:
        logger.error('ERROR', exc_info=True)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: Sure. Just added. Thanks @Patrik

Comment: did you get any solution??